# How to check domain

Tags: javascript

I use JavaScript to insert the specific into the page. The problem is that it is necessery to load this iframe for the specific domain. I mean like in GoogleMaps, where you have to insert special key to be able load maps for your domain.

In few words I want to check where my script is linked from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not get the parent property if your page is not on the same domain, the only solutions is to check the document referrer

```
var ref = document.referrer;
alert(ref);
```

Comment: And even the referrer wont work if the user clicks on some link in the iframe and the iframe loads again.

Comment: Okay. If it wasn't an iframe, how does the GoogleMap works? In APIv2 I had to insert the key generated for my domain. And when the domain of the page where I use maps changed I get an error - something like "Wrong key for that domain".
All I need is to prevent loading the data from the wrong domain. But  if I use the key - someone can see it in the page source and insert on his page.

Comment: well, i mean to say that You can only check the referrer. So get the referrer check that in your db, if this domain is allowed or not. Then display content or dont load any thing. Its upto you how you work with this single piece of information